# Real time Data Extraction from SAP ECC

Tags: azure, odata, azure-data-factory, sap-erp, sap-gateway

We have requirement to extract data from ECC tables to Azure data lake in real time.
Azure data factory has connectivity option to SAP ECC system but it will not support real time ingestion.

Please let me know if there is any native implementation available within Azure / SAP  to support this type of requirement.

Answer (score 1):

For real-time ingestion scenarios, you can use the SAP change data capture (CDC) solution in Azure Data Factory. See [SAP change data capture (CDC) solution in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/sap-change-data-capture-introduction-architecture) The native connector is in Public Preview at the moment.